# Firebase and Express, my api sends duplicate response each time the value of firebase is changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I am beginner in express js, i made api for my music app from express and firebase, that takes data from firebase and takes request and send data as response. But there is problem which is messing the program. Each time the value (`Views` of music) of firebase changes it re sends the same response.

heres my code

```js
app.use(cors())
let trendingTracks = []
let data;
function Trending(data){
    if (data){
        Object.values(data).forEach((value)=>{
            if(value.views < 10){
                trendingTracks.push(value)
            }
        })
    }
}

function SortPopular(a){
    for(let i = 0; i<=a.length; i++){
        for (let j = i+1; j<a.length; j++){
            if(a[i].views>a[j].views){
                const temp = a[i]
                a[i]=a[j]
                a[j]=temp 
            }
        }
    }
    return a
}

firebase.database().ref("public/songs").on("value", snapshot =>{
    data = snapshot.val();
    Trending(data)
})

app.get("/api/home/trending", (req, res)=>{
    res.send(SortPopular(trendingTracks))
})

app.listen(4000, ()=>console.log("listening at port 4000..."))
```

This is what my database looks like:
[image]

And each time `views` value changes it re response the same data.

When the value of database is not changed:

[image]

When the value of database is changed:

[image]

As you can see the same thing re sends.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see your whole code, so I cannot be 100% sure, but I suspect it happens because you are constantly adding items to `trendingTracks`, but need to actually clear it every time you run `Trending` function.

So add `trendingTracks = []` as in here:

```js
app.use(cors())
let trendingTracks = []
let data;
function Trending(data){
    if (data){
        trendingTracks = [] // NEW
        Object.values(data).forEach((value)=>{
            if(value.views < 10){
                trendingTracks.push(value)
            }
        })
    }
}

function SortPopular(a){
    for(let i = 0; i<=a.length; i++){
        for (let j = i+1; j<a.length; j++){
            if(a[i].views>a[j].views){
                const temp = a[i]
                a[i]=a[j]
                a[j]=temp 
            }
        }
    }
    return a
}

firebase.database().ref("public/songs").on("value", snapshot =>{
    data = snapshot.val();
    Trending(data)
})

app.get("/api/home/trending", (req, res)=>{
    res.send(SortPopular(trendingTracks))
})
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Please also accept my solution (click on the tick symbol below the voting buttons). Thanks! :)